# Using sections inside flexbox image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an image gallery using a flexbox layout. This is how it's supposed to look in the end:

[image]

This is basically just a flexbox with images inside:

```
<div class="flexbox-grid">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DjLPhu1.png">
    ...
 </div>

.flexbox-grid {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  
img {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

But now I want to add sections to groups of images for some js scripts. Like this:

```
<section id="first">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DjLPhu1.png">
</section>
<section id="second">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DjLPhu1.png">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DjLPhu1.png">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DjLPhu1.png">
</section>
```

Of course this completely messes up the grid layout, as now the grouped images are kept together:
[image]

How do I add sections (or divs) here and still keep the initial grid layout? The elements I actually want to have a flexbox for are the children of the sections, not the sections themselves.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/8f2mv7cb/1/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe what the JS needs? For example could you group the imgs using a class rather than in a section - you could still get all the images in a group.

Comment: display:contents on section

Comment: @AHaworth The JS is mainly there for highlighting elements in my sidebar. So I have this gallery and the images are grouped in sections. And a sidebar menu shows in which section I am at the moment. Right now I actually added a class with its group name to every single image, but that feels really hacky, so I'd like to just have sections.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. @TemaniAfif has as ever come up with an elegant solution, which I didn't previously know existed like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be more of a task for CSS grid layout. Then you could arrange the rows and columns to fit how you want it and give classes to them or certain parts of it which gives your scripts more freedom.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll take a look at this, thank you. Actually didn't know it existed.